# Rational cohomology cohomology of $p$-adic analytic groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, lie-algebra-cohomology

It is a result of Lazard that given $G$ a compact $p$-adic analytic group then we have an isomorphism
\begin{equation} H^*(G; \mathbb{Q}_p) \cong H^*(T_eG; \mathbb{Q}_p) \end{equation}
where $T_eG$ is the tangent space of $G$ at $e$, which is isomorphic to the space of left-invariant vector spaces so it is a Lie algebra and the term on the right hand side refers to Lie algebra cohomology.

The most modern account I can think of this fact is the paper "Cohomology of $p$-adic Analytic Groups" by Symonds and Weigel. Here this appears in far greater generality as Theorem 5.2.4. The proof consists in direct manipulation of projective resolutions used to compute the cohomology groups present to find a chain of quasi isomorphisms between the cochain complexes involved.

In their paper Symonds and Weigel develop a comprehensive theory of continuous cohomology for such groups as derived functors of exact functors between exact categories (not necessarily abelian!). Instead I am skipping on these homological foundations and I am considering for $M$ a continuous $G$-module the groups $H^*(G;M)$ just to be the cohomology of the cochain complex associated to the cosimplicial abelian group $k \mapsto C_G(G^{k+1}, M)$, where $C_G(A,B)$ indicated the space of continuous $G$-equivariant maps between two $G$-spaces $A$ and $B$.

With this approach I cannot adapt the proof I mentioned since I have not related such cohomology groups to derived functors. So I wanted to ask if you have any idea how to prove this statement with the minimal homology theory effort: we know that $H^*(T_eG; \mathbb{Q}_p)$ is the cohomology associated to Chevalley complex of the Lie algebra $T_eG$ and for $H^*(G;\mathbb{Q}_p)$ we start already with a cochain complex defining it. So I had in mind to find a chain of quasi-isomorphisms between them but I had no success whatsoever. I also thought that maybe another possible ingredient is the cochain complex of differential forms on $G$, which is quasi-isomorphic to the Chevalley complex as usual. But again I cannot find a reasonable way to relate this to $C_G(G^{\bullet +1}, \mathbb{Q}_p)$.

The point where I am stuck is that I have no intuitive idea of any "geometric" information encoded by the cochain complex of equivariant maps, thus I cannot connect this to the differential forms or left invariant vector fields. Any pointer in this direction is welcomed.